# What is the derivative of $y = \int_{0}^x t f(x^2-t^2)dt$?

Tags: calculus

Let $y = \int_{0}^x t f(x^2-t^2)dt$, where $f$ is differentiable. How to compute $\frac{dy}{dx}$?

My solution: I think that 
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \int_{0}^x 2x t f'(x^2 - t^2)dt + tf(0). 
$$
Is this correct? Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you want the last term on the right-hand side to be $x f(0)$.

Comment: @Max, yes, thank you very much.

Comment: Then it looks right to me. You can compare with this formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Comment: @Max, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g:\Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R$, $\Delta:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R^2$ is the diagonal map, and $f(x)=g(x,x)$ (or $f=g\circ \Delta$) then the chain rule gives $f'(x)=g_1(x,x)+g_2(x,x)$ (where $g_i$ is the $i$th partial derivative).

Letting $g(x,y)=\int_{0}^x t f(y^2-t^2)dt$ gives the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x^2-t^2=m$.

And  $-2tdt=dm$.

$\int_0^x tf(x^2-t^2) dt=\int_{x^2}^0 tf(m) \frac{dm}{-2t}$
$=-\frac{1}{2} \int_{x^2}^0 f(m) dm$

Hence,

$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xtf(x^2-t^2) dt=-\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dx}  \int_{x^2}^0 f(m) dm=xf(x^2)$